# Reset DHCP IP's on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ip, google-compute-engine

Actually when I create a new machine in GCP, the google compute engine is assigning to me an IP 1xx. 
Only I have arround 30 machines, but, when kubernetes generate a new node, the IP is incremented.
How I can reset this IP pool?

For example now I'm trying to generate a marketplace deploy (rabbitmq) and isn't possible to reserve internal IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL**;**DR**: CGE Instances supports two types of internal IP addresses: Static Internal and Ephemeral. For both cases, IPs remain attached to a resource until they are explicitly detached from the resource. So if you can't reserve more IP addresses is because you ran out of IP addresses.

Google released a document named [IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses) where it explains how IP addresses are assigned to resources within GCP.

Based on your question, seems that you have [custom VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#vpc_networks_and_subnets). The error you get is because you ran out of IP addresses.

Ephemeral IP addresses are released when the resource is deleted. But Static Internal Addresses are not automatically deleted when the resource is deleted, it only gets detached. Most likely you have a lot of reserved addresses not attached to resources.

Lastly, Stackoverflow may be not the best forum for this question. I highly recommend you to share your question in [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) since is a better forum for infrastructure questions.

Comment: Thanks, I post the same question over Serverfault.